# Where to send people for product recommendations?

Tags: discussion

B.SE isn't the place to ask for product recommendations (I've seen said several times), but people need to ask about specific bike products because the universe of products is so large.  Finding one's way to a suitable product in that universe is a huge amount of work, and a suggestion or two from someone who's already done this can save a lot of time.

Is there a place we can send people for recommendations?  A list of sites to refer them to?  In other words, if one needs product recommendations, where *is* the right place to ask?

Comment: Product recs are bad because they get outdated quickly. Stores go bust, product lines change, etc. I usually give a recommendation in a comment like this then flag the question for moderation.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I generally refer people looking for a specific product recommendation to our [Velodrome Chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/?tab=site&host=bicycles.stackexchange.com). That way they can have the kind of back and forth that is useful in determining a specific need, as well as talk to those who may be knowledgeable about current products.

Answer (score 3):

[Bikeforums](http://www.bikeforums.net/) or any other cycling forum is probably a decent bet.

Answer (score 2):

If the question is interesting and it's not too much work, linking to a relevant review of such products in a comment is helpful to the OP.  This doesn't prevent me casting a close vote at the same time. Such reviews can often be [surprisingly specific](http://www.cyclingabout.com/list-of-convertible-backpack-panniers-that-can-be-strapped-to-your-back-or-bike/).

Answer (score 0):

If its software specific, then SE has a stack called http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/